# A password has to use the following format: LDDDDLLL

Tags: probability, combinations

A password has to use the following format: LDDDDLLL, where L can be any of the upper case letters in the alphabet, and D can be any digit including 0. None of the digits or letters can repeat.

a) What is the probability that the 4 uppercase letters in the password spells the word “MATH?”

I got that the total number of possible outcomes is 26 choose 4 x 10 choose 4 which equals 3139500. I'm not sure if that's right, but i'm stuck in finding out how much of the outcomes allow the 4 uppercase letters in the password to spell MATH?

Comment: Do you want the 4 upper case letters to be MATH?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: yes, the 4 upper case letters are supposed to be math

Comment: Is this from an "invent the most obnoxious password firmat rules that also make passwords unnecessarily easy to crack" contest?

Answer (score 1):

This answer preassumes that the order does not count so that also e.g. $A,M,T,H$ spells MATH.

---

The number of possible outcomes if the letters come from $\{A,B,\dots,Z\}$ is $26P4\times10P4$.

Similarly the number of possible outcomes if the letters come from $\{M,A,T,H\}$ is $4P4\times10P4$.

So the searched probability is: $$\frac{4P4\times 10P4}{26P4\times 10P4}=\frac{4P4}{26P4}$$

If order does matter then $4P4$ must be replaced by $1$.

Also note that actually it is enough to look at the letters only.

(Here $26P4$ denotes $26\times25\times24\times23$)